# What is this dislocated hard disk component?

Tags: hard-drive

These are three pictures of a crashed internal Toshiba hard disk that I am trying to fix. I was wondering if you could identify this particular part which looks like its from the read-head stack but I don't know where it fits?

Any help would be great. And yes, I will be giving it to a expert to fix, I just need to know where it goes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ***you opened the hard drive?!*** Thats literally the worst thing you could have done.

Comment: Yeah, it no longer really matters where it goes. You opened the drive outside a clean room; you killed it.

Comment: Hi guys, guest101/the OP here: well i did take the precaution to open the HDD in a room that is dust free, used the utmost precaution to open it up, did not plug in the power when opened, and did not try to move the read heads. Believe me i was careful. I opened it up because its a hardware failure on the HDD and i cant afford to get a data recovery expert for the data, which is basically only a months worth of stuff.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, it doesnt really matter.  If the platters survive until the time you take it to a data recovery specialist, they would just remove the platters and put them in a special machine.  However, with the platters exposed to open air, its a ticking time bomb with a very short fuse.  Put the cover back on, put it in a plastic bag, take it to a recovery specialist ASAP and *pray* they can get ***anything*** off of it.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But i still would like to know if possible just what part IS IT and where did it come off from. if anyone needs any more pictures i can oblige. I know there is a slim to none chance in recovering any data, i dont have any illusions about it. I remember a while ago when the reeadheads were stuck on another drive, used a screw to turn the platter counter-clockwise and simultaneously gently brought the arms back off the platter. Drive worked, he got the data off, and its still working fine.